# How does perspective transformation work? [OpenCV python]

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix, homography

Part of my dissertation involves rectifying a section of an image that is not in perfect frontal perspective. I can't add images because of my low score, but it's essentially this [python code (with images)](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/).

I've already built the program and it works, but I don't understand the math behind it. I've looked into matrix image rectification and homography, but there is a huge skill gap to the point I can't understand any of it. I'm not sure where to start learning the math. I know the basics of matrices and that's about it. I want to get to the point where I can code the matrix transformation function myself.

In an nutshell, what do I need to "study" to understand the math?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it's impossible, but you can try.
In fact, projective geometry is a deep mathematical concept that is studied in mathematical specialties of universities. If you really want to understand it well, you have to become a bit of a mathematician.
Projective geometry is studied after linear algebra, analytic geometry and affine geometry, in this sequence.
But I doubt you need it all.
You can consider a simplified approach focused on image processing, such as [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1818E372016712B7329B8172B2D63470?doi=10.1.1.17.1329&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [here](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/isprs96/isprs96.html)

Answer (score 1):

A perspective transformation is simply a fractional linear equation that is solved from a matrix formation.

The fractional linear equation is of the form that is linear in the numerator and linear in the denominator, i.e. first order terms at the highest in both numerator and denominator.

```
x = (P1*u + P2*v + P3) / (P7*u + P8*v + 1)
y = (P4*u + P5*v + P6) / (P7*u + P8*v + 1)
```

where x,y are the input coordinates and u,v are the output coordinates. (The inverse is also fractional linear, so it has the same form)

In matrix form, this is:

```
(x)  =  ( P1  P2  P3 )  (u)
(y)     ( P4  P5  P6 )  (v)
(1)     ( P7  P8   1 )  (1)
```

The seven unknown Ps can be solved by simultaneous equations from 4 (or more) pairs of conjugate input and output coordinates.